# relative postion css extjs Sencha touch

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm working in Sencha Touch framework, I've created to boxes (for example) and want to give the **outterbox** relative to the **innerbox**, which has fixed position. But unfortunatly, my image wont show if the position is kept as `relative` (any one of that wont show if it has a relative positon property).

My Question is, how can I relate two `CSS` classes/id in `Extjs/javascript` as my target is to give them a rotation, only possible when they have this property according to my knowledge.

Any other suggestions are welcomed.

```
#outterbox {
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  background-image:url('outterbox.png');
  position: relative; // not showing
}
#innerbox {
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  background-image:url('innerbox.png');
  position: fixed;

}
```

Comment: an image showing what you want to achieve would be handy. Also this doesn't seem to have anyhting to do with sencha-touch, either you're missing code or this is a pure css question

Comment: @lascort yeah this is pure CSS, but it is showing fine in normal CSS/HTML view but wont show in EXTJS/Sencha Touch framework. I want to achieve a rotation of two object relative to each other.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. I want to rotate two boxes relative to each other. Just for example, like a compass and needle to show the direction. @lascort